# Setting focus on login via Selenium Webdriver for Robot to work

Tags: java, selenium

I'm testing an internal website that can only be accessed via internet explorer that uses windows authentication to validate a users credentials and have to test multiple accounts, so I need to be able to "log in" to the website as different people (I previously contemplated having several machines each logged in as the relevant accounts but cant do this).

If I go to the page as my webdriver account I get a standard internet explorer "Windows Security" popup where I can enter my login details without a problem.  Only issue so far is webdriver doesn't recognise the popup.

I thought I could use the Java Robot class to do this and have ripped off some code I found to plug into my Selenium webdriver scripts and it *almost* works, trouble is it only works if I manually click on the login window presented for it to copy and paste the details (see code below).  Any suggestions as to how I can use Selenium or robot to set focus on this object before copying and pasting?

```
public Boolean loginDetails(individualThreadSession threadSesh){
        Action myAction = new Action();
        final String USERNAME= "loginID";
        final String PASSWORD= "myPassword";
        myAction.simpleWait(1);

        Robot robot = null;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        type(robot, USERNAME);
        myAction.simpleWait(1);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        myAction.simpleWait(1);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

        myAction.simpleWait(1);

        type(robot, PASSWORD);
        myAction.simpleWait(1);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        myAction.simpleWait(1);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        myAction.simpleWait(1);

        return(true);
    }

    public static void type(Robot robot, String characters) {
        Action myAction = new Action(); 
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection( characters );
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        myAction.simpleWait(1);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        myAction.simpleWait(1);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        myAction.simpleWait(1);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        myAction.simpleWait(1);
    }
```

I've also tried just entering the individual key strokes instead of copy and pasting the information but that does work either, I need to give the screen focus before it'll work... :S

Also tried this but still doesn't set focus on the Windows Security dialog...

```
Alert aa = threadSesh.driver.switchTo().alert();
aa.sendKeys(USERNAME);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the focus is not present on the authentication window. You cannot try ALT+TAB with Robot as it is not a seperate window. For your scenario i think "AutoIT" can be appropriate solution. If you want to go ahead with AutoIT, let me know i can send some sample code.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.sun.jna.WString;

public interface AutoITX extends com.sun.jna.Library, Serializable {

public static int AU3_INTDEFAULT = -2147483647;

public int AU3_WinWaitActive(WString szTitle, WString szText, int nTimeout);

    }
```

Create an object for AutoITX say objAutoIT. Call the WinWaitActivate() with below parameters.
Replace windowTitle, windowText(can be empty), waitTime as per your requirement.

```
    objAutoIT.AU3_WinWaitActive(WString(windowTitle), WString(windowText), waitTimeInSecs);
```

Comment: I really don't want to have to involve another piece of software if at all possible but if there isn't an alternative in java/robot/selenium I guess I'll have to investigate this option... :S

Comment: Any ideas how I can script a simple autoit exe to just set focus on the security dialog popup?  So I can then use sendkey within selenium?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to create a standalone exe using autoit (the software to write and compile could be better I must say but its free so I can't complain) with the following code: -

Func _WinWaitActivate($title,$text,$timeout=100)
    WinWait($title,$text,$timeout)
    If Not WinActive($title,$text) Then WinActivate($title,$text)
    WinWaitActive($title,$text,$timeout)
EndFunc

```
_WinWaitActivate("Windows Security","")
Send("myloginID{TAB}mypassword{ENTER}")
```

I then call that within my code with the following once I've navigated to the page that brings up the popup: -

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\test\\test.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And hey presto!  The minute that login appears it enters the login details...  I suppose it'l have to do for now! :)